# For loop runs twice but ArrayAdapter in it get only the second result

Tags: android, arrays, for-loop, amazon-dynamodb

I have this `for` loop in an `AsyncTask` in my code in the `doInBackground` method:

```
Object[] strings = prefItems.getStringSet("items", null).toArray();
for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
        DynamoDBScanExpression scan = new DynamoDBScanExpression();
        Condition condition = new Condition()
                .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.EQ)
                .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withS(strings[i].toString()));
        scan.addFilterCondition("id", condition);
        List<Item> addedItems = dbMapper.scan(Item.class, scan);
        ArrayList<Item> alp = new ArrayList<Item>();
        for (Item item: addedItems) {
            item.setName(item.getName());
            item.setId(item.getId());
            alp.add(item);
        }
    }
```

On the `onPostExecute` method I have this code:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
ListViewAdapter adapt = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, alp);
lv.setAdapter(adapt);
```

There are 2 Strings in `strings`.

The code suppose to take every string from the `Object[]` and search for an equal item in a DynamoDB table. For some reason it shows results only for the second item in the array.

I've tried to show the items as a text, so when I wrote "the second item in the array", I meant in an alphabetic order, since that how it shows as a string.

According to the length of `strings`, the code suppose to run only 2 times. When `i = 0` and `i = 1`, but for some reason it runs only when `i = 1`, so it shows only the second item, and not also the first one.

I thought about it, and I think it has something to do with the `onPostExecute` method code. In the code it takes `alp` as an adapter. Maybe it something related to it?

Can you please help me? I'm stuck with that problem for over 3 days and I have to end this project by the end of the week.

How can I set `alp` to contain more than one item from the string array at a time?

Comment: Can you confirm it is actually size 2?

Comment: Yes. I set it as a text for TextView and I got this result: [a, b]. As I wrote in the question I get only the result that is equal to b in the array.

Comment: okay, try to change from Object[] to Strings

Comment: I've already tried it. It doesn't work

Comment: Next, try to use a foreach instead of fori?

Comment: You should use the debugger to identify the issue.

Comment: @Eenvincible I've tried to use `foreach`. It didn't work. @manfcas I not really familiar with the debugger and how to use it...

Comment: Why are you passing null to a method when getting StringSet?

Comment: @Eenvincible What am I supposed to pass instead of `null`?

Comment: Well, if you wrote that method yourself, you would need to change the signature; is that method from prefItems? By the way, can you share how you read from preferences?

Comment: @Eenvincible I didn't understand what you meant. Can you explain?

Comment: Share code that you use to get prefItems?

Comment: @Eenvincible I've added it to code in my question.

Comment: Can someone please help me with my question?

Comment: I've updated the question with more code and info. Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by moving this line:

```
ArrayList<Item> alp = new ArrayList<Item>();
```

To the `onCreate` method so it won't loop it self, and delete the `ArrayList` contents by that.

Answer (score -2):

Try to change this line

```
for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++)
```

to:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= strings.length; i++)
```

Comment: It has to be less than the length because the actual length will throw indexOutofBounds exeception